# Activating BCS in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, bcs, database, server

I'm wanting to use BCS in my SharePoint environment and i came to the problem of the database.

Can we connect multiple databases on different servers?

Can we select the database from its IP address and not from a name?

I've seen some tutorials on the internet and they are all about using the server name and I don't know where exactly I can use an IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You can create different external systems for each of the database server. And use the external system while creation ECT's. I am not use using IP vs Name has any impact as both should resolve as expected.